# Using mathematical expression in legends and ylab

Tags: r

I have a problem in using mathematical expressions in R for plots. For Example:

```
x=seq(1,10,0.1)
y=log(x)
plot(x,y,"l",xlab=expression(H[alpha]^beta*(P)),ylab=expression(H[tau]^beta*(P)))
legend("bottom",legend=c(expression(H[alpha]^beta*(P),"=1")),cex=1)
```

In y-axix label, half of the beta is invisible where as in case of x-axix label, it is ok. Also in legends while i am trying to write an expression in single row but it takes two rows, "=1" it takes in second row.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
x=seq(1,10,0.1)
y=log(x)
par(mgp=c(2.5,1,.0))
plot(x,y,"l",xlab=expression(H[alpha]^beta*(P)),ylab=expression(H[tau]^beta*(P)))
legend("bottom",legend=expression(H[alpha]^beta*(P)==1),cex=1,text.width=2)
```